# How to handle a breakdown in communication in the comments

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I have a general question prompted by a specific event.

I often see comments where two users cannot seem to get on the same page. Eventually a prompt appears to move into chat which is helpful in lots of cases. But also frequently, the communication breaks down and the argument gets rather heated.

I'm not sure there's a clear cut answer as (with most things involving people) every situation is unique. The specific situation I'm referring to are the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297425/is-it-possible-to-render-svg-radial-gradients-with-gradienttransforms-in-userspa/68310594#68310594). The reason I'm unsure is that it appears from the communication that there were more comments which were removed previously, and now coming across it as a newcomer I don't feel I have all of the information.

The question is what should a passive observer of such a breakdown in communication do? Which flag or flags is most appropriate for this situation? And how should the linked offsite documents be handled as they are offsite documents, but do contain a *lot* of text?

Comment: Disengage and flag whatever needs to be flagged. If you can't get the information you need to answer, remember that it's still your choice if you want to keep digging. If OP isn't interested, don't waste your time on that question.

Comment: Would you consider the content of the pastebins as part of the comments for the purposes of flag reason?

Comment: To clarify, it's not my question, nor my answer. This is a question I came across in my review queue.

Comment: My bad, missed that detail - and yes. The pastebin was used to bypass comment length restrictions - its content is relevant. You're probably better off mod-flagging the answer and explaining that the comments are a dumpster fire in need of some or complete removal though. Mods some times miss context (blame the tools for that) with certain comment sections that just escalate, making a mod flag better when you're walking into it a bit after the fact.

Comment: If the comments are getting heated, then flag them as Unfriendly or as Abusive, if appropriate. If the comment chain is no longer relevant, use a custom flag on the answer and ask for it to be cleaned up. If neither applies then...I don't see why you need to do anything. Leave the users to iron it out. Either they reach an agreement or not. There is nothing an outside observer can really do. Nor should they. At most suggest they start a chat room. But I'd probably not. No real reason.

Comment: 1/2 (I should learn concision...) FWIW, **I** did mess up engaging like that with them. I did my best to not loose my temper and try to make them come back to the tracks of our community standards, but doing so, I myself did cross the line. It happens to me, I'm sorry. I guess a third voice could have helped **me** disengage from there, but this might work only for me, so prefer the community's solution(s) provided below. Regarding the mod's intervention, it was entirely well handled by the moderator: At the time they did intervene, there were only two comments that were really "hot"

Comment: 2/2 (one in each side I must admit with shame...) Unfortunately, lost in the heat was a link to a fiddle that I thought was useful for OP and future readers and would close the whole dilemma. How wrong could I be... Here the whole forest got burning and in the panic I couldn't escape. I was really (stupidly) hoping to still be able to reason with my interlocutor, and since I couldn't invite them to chat I did this bad thing of bypassing the comments limit (note that I did since remove the link). I myself missed a good part of the last episode of the story, but it's definitely a good thing.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm only seeing the aftermath, but the tone in a couple of the surviving (upvoted) comments doesn't look good to me, however justified it may have felt at the time: _"And for the last time..."_ and _"Did you actually read the two sentences I wrote in my answer?..."_. No big deal; you were clearly trying hard to help, but the use of passive-aggressive phrases like that on SO is inappropriate now. TLDR: if someone doesn't really want to be helped, just walk away.

Comment: @skomisa I totally agree I was borderline, you know how it is, you lose your keys the morning and then... If memory serves well (mine rarely does), in the first case I don't think I meant to be passive aggressive but more trying to express some surprise, but from retrospect I do read it like you do. My English really doesn't help, but I put it mainly on my own temper. In the second case, that was after about 3 times me trying to explain them with various tones the same thing and I did receive a few comments that did sound insulting to me, I really was hoping that would be the "last" time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> The question is what should a passive observer of such a breakdown in communication do?

Firstly, "we" should not be *telling* the passive observer what to do.  So these should be viewed as suggestions.

1. Don't get involved.  It is unlikely to help.  Even polite suggestions to "everyone calm down" are unlikely to help.

(Aside: If you *want* to get involved, you stop being a passive observer, and turn into an active participant.  Now you may choose to do that anyway ... but it won't help to "restore civil order".)

2. If the conversation shows the signs of going from "vigorous but healthy discussion" to "unpleasant":

   - Flag comments that are pointless and unhelpful as "no longer needed"<sup>1</sup>.
   - Flag comments that are unambiguously rude or disrespectful as "rude and offensive".
   - If it really gets bad, flag the answer or the question as needing moderator attention.

   Then let the diamond moderators deal with it.  They are experienced with dealing with this kind of thing, *and* they have some powerful tools to use when necessary.

---

In the example that you presented, it appears that moderators did step in and delete some comments.  And maybe other things.  This is how it is supposed to work.

---

<sup>1 - Comments (correctly) flagged as "no longer needed" don't count as a black mark against anyone.</sup>

Comment: "*My understanding is that comments (correctly) flagged as "no longer needed" way don't count as a black mark against anyone.*" they don't. NLN is completely neutral. E.g., if I ask a question for clarification in a comment and OP adds the information, anybody is free to flag my comment as NLN as the clarification was added.

Comment: [Telling someone to calm down can most certainly escalate things](https://drsusanbernstein.com/dont-tell-an-upset-person-calm-down-%E2%80%8B-do-this-instead/). You're just telling them to stop feeling what they're feeling without addressing the reason for those feelings in any way. It's probably less likely to be an issue if you weren't personally involved in the argument, but it still doesn't seem like a particularly good idea.

Comment: Telling **everyone** to calm down is a bit different.  But yea, I agree it typically won't help.

Comment: Thank you @StephenC This is mostly what I was thinking and how I handled the situation, but happy to have some confirmation. The big piece that made me unsure was how to handle the offsite content. The thing I didn't know is if the letter form pastebins which, as Zoe put it , were "used to bypass comment length restrictions" counted as "content" in terms of flagging.

Comment: I don't want to insinuate that sometimes questions are "over-moderated", but I do notice that when the community has an unfavorable reaction to a question posted by somebody that has a new account that it tends to snowball, particularly when the question is over-researched or overly specific relative to the user's reputation.

Comment: I'd have to add that there are some (few) times that an outside observer can help calm down a heated discussion. Usually that means being able to see what the disconnect between the participants is and being able to clearly explain and/or correct it. This has to be done carefully or one person may misinterpret it as you "ganging up" on them and further escalating the situation. So yes, oftentimes, staying out of the conversation is the best option.